# want to show record of same date previous and next time slot for a given date

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with multiple record against userid and datetime fields. A user have availability for same date everyhour.

```
UserId         DateTime
1           2018-08-13 08:30:00 +05:30
1           2018-08-13 09:30:00 +05:30
1           2018-08-13 10:30:00 +05:30
1           2018-08-13 15:00:00 +05:30
1           2018-08-13 17:00:00 +05:30
1           2018-08-13 18:00:00 +05:30
```

Now If I search for date suppose 2018-08-13 **11:30:00** +05:30
then I want in

`Previous slot = 2018-08-13 **10:30:00** +05:30`

and `next slot = 2018-08-13 **15:00:00** +05:30`

**Update**

Quick update I need smaller time for the same date not the previous day. Ex. For 
`2018-08-13 08:30:00 +05:30` it should show `null` as no small time available.

Answer (score 2):

One more try with CTEs, edited to match the changed question:

```
DECLARE @SearchDate datetime = '2018-08-13 11:30:00',
        @StartDate datetime,
        @EndDate datetime,
        @UserId int = 1;

SET @StartDate = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@SearchDate), MONTH(@SearchDate), DAY(@SearchDate), 0, 0, 0, 0);
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @StartDate);

WITH 
ctePrevious AS
(
    SELECT MAX([DateTime]) AS [DateTime] 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE UserId = @UserId AND [DateTime] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @SearchDate
),
cteNext AS
(
    SELECT MIN([DateTime]) AS [DateTime] 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE UserId = @UserId AND [DateTime] BETWEEN @SearchDate AND @EndDate
)
SELECT ctePrevious.[DateTime] AS prevDate, cteNext.[DateTime] AS nextDate
FROM ctePrevious, cteNext
```

It should return NULL values if no entry is found for the given date.

Comment: Thanks @bpaul. [DateTime] <= SearchDate by this I will get all dates smaller then this date. I just need all small dates for the same date, it means for 2018-08-13 i need only smaller time if exists not need 12th aug smallest time.

Comment: @vikas: I changed my answer, hope this helps you.

Comment: THanks @Bpaul yes it is giving right result set but looks very heavy query with too much scan and select. any optimized way?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a rownumber and a self join. The following example will demonstrate how it works:

```
CREATE TABLE  #T (ID INT, DateT DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1, GETDATE() - .2)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1, GETDATE() - .1)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1, GETDATE() - .05)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1, GETDATE() + .1);


WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumb
    FROM #T AS T
)

SELECT C.ID, C.DateT AS StartDate, C2.DateT AS EndDate
FROM CTE AS C
LEFT JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C.RowNumb = C2.RowNumb - 1
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN C.DateT AND C2.DateT -- your date input here
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `LEAD` and `LAG`. This is Pseudo SQL, however:

```
SELECT DateColumn,
       LAG(DateColumn) OVER (ORDER BY DateColumn) AS Previousslot,
       LEAD(DateColumn) OVER (ORDER BY DateColumn) AS NextSlot
FROM YourTable;
```

This, unlike SQL_M's answer, means you don't need to do 2/3 scans of the table.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu it almost working fine but when I am passing a specific date with where clause it is showing nothing like where datecolumn= "2018-08-13 15:00:00 +05:30"

Comment: If I am not passing any date then it is showing next day slot as NextTime I need null if nothing available that day

Comment: You'll need a DateCalendar for that. A dataset that contains no rows will not return `NULL`. It'll return no rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @wantedDate datetime = '2018-09-04 12:27:16.570'
select top 1 * from #t tP       -- Top of each min and max time
join #T tn
on tp.ID = tn.ID
and tp.DateT <= @wantedDate     -- all previous times
and tn.DateT >= @wantedDate     -- all next times
order by tp.ID, tp.DateT desc, tn.DateT
```

Revert me, if query needs updates.